# Mongo Aggregate group two field in a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have query something like this.

```
db.getCollection('wifi_sessions_90').aggregate([
    { $match: {Datetime: {$gt: new Date(new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14))}}},
    {
        $project:{
            uploadType:{
                    $switch:{
                        branches:[
                        {
                                case:{ $gt : ['$Upload', 2147483648] },
                                then: "> 2Gb"
                        },
                        {
                                case:{ $and : [{ $gt : ['$Upload', 1073741824] }, { $lt : ['$Upload',2147483648] }]},
                                then: "1 - 2Gb"
                        },
                        {
                                case:{ $and : [{ $gt : ['$Upload', 524288000] }, { $lt : ['$Upload',1073741824] }]},
                                then: "500Mb - 1Gb"
                        }
                        ],
                        default: "< 500Mb"
                    }
            },
            downloadType:{
                    $switch:{
                        branches:[
                        {
                                case:{ $gt : ['$Download', 2147483648] },
                                then: "> 2Gb"
                        },
                        {
                                case:{ $and : [{ $gt : ['$Download', 1073741824] }, { $lt : ['$Download',2147483648] }]},
                                then: "1 - 2Gb"
                        },
                        {
                                case:{ $and : [{ $gt : ['$Download', 524288000] }, { $lt : ['$Download',1073741824] }]},
                                then: "500Mb - 1Gb"
                        }
                        ],
                        default: "< 500Mb"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

It will categorize every document 'Upload' and 'Download' to its own category. Then I will group it for example for upload

```
{ $group :
    {
        _id :
        {
            uploadType : '$uploadType'
        },
        count : { $sum: 1 }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve for 'Download' in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull them into array before group.

Something like

```
[
 {"$project":{
    "types":[
      {"name":"uploadType",
      "value":{"$switch":{...}}},
      {"name":"downloadType",
       "value":{"$switch":{...}}}
    ]
 }},
 {"$unwind":"$types"},
 {"$group":{
   "_id":{"name":"$types.name","value":"$types.value"},
   "count":{"$sum":1}
 }}
]
```